# Optimize a trading strategy created in excel with R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio-optimization, excel

I have created quite a complex back test in excel spanning 15 years with 17 parameters. I would like to optimize the parameters which would give me maximum return given a maximum draw-down percentage. Is it possible to optimize it without actually coding the strategy in R or similar software that have optimization capabilities?

Comment: Did you try the Excel Solver? It's not the best solver available but it might just work.

Comment: Solving for 17 parameters over 15 years is quite a lot for excel solver to handle.

Comment: ...beware data snooping bias!